# Firebase Auth: updateProfile in Cloud Function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I tried to use updateProfile() in my Cloud Function, triggered by HTTPS.

**Error:**

> user.updateProfile is not a function

**Cloud Function:**

```
app.get("/user/create", (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')

    admin.auth().verifyIdToken(req.query.token).then(user => {
        let name = req.query.name

        user.updateProfile({
            displayName: name
        }).then(() => {
            res.send(JSON.stringify({
                result: false,
                error: err.message
            }))
        })

    })
})
```

The error makes totally sense to me, but I've no clue how I can get a actual user reference to update the profile, any idea?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're assuming that verifyIdToken() generates a promise that contains a User object.  That's not the case here.  According to [the API docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#verifyIdToken), it provides a [DecodedIdToken](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.DecodedIdToken) object.  That object contains a uid property with the UID of the user represented by the token you passed to it.

If you want to get a [UserRecord](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserRecord) object from there, you can call [admin.auth().getUser(uid)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#getUser) with that UID.  However, that won't help you update the user's profile.

If you want to update the profile for a given UID, you can call [admin.auth().updateUser(uid, properties)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#updateUser).